# Django compare values of two objects

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter

I have a Django model that looks something like this:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    transcript = models.TextField(null=True)

class Coding(models.Model):
    qid = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response)
    coder = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

For each Response object, there are two coding objects with qid = "risk", one for coder 3 and one for coder 4. What I would like to be able to do is get a list of all Response objects for which the difference in value between coder 3 and coder 4 is greater than 1. The value field stores numbers 1-7.

I realize in hindsight that setting up value as a CharField may have been a mistake, but hopefully I can get around that.

I believe something like the following SQL would do what I'm looking for, but I'd rather do this with the ORM

```
SELECT UNIQUE c1.response_id FROM coding c1, coding c2
WHERE c1.coder_id = 3 AND 
      c2.coder_id = 4 AND
      c1.qid = "risk" AND 
      c2.qid = "risk" AND
      c1.response_id = c2.response_id AND
      c1.value - c2.value > 1
```

Comment: I think you meant to include `c1.response_id = c2.response_id` in the WHERE clause of your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F
qset = Coding.objects.filter(response__coding__value__gt=F('value') + 1,
                             qid='risk',  coder=4
                    ).extra(where=['T3.qid = %s', 'T3.coder_id = %s'],
                            params=['risk', 3])
responses = [c.response for c in qset.select_related('response')]
```

When you join to a table already in the query, the ORM will assign the second one an alias, in this case T3, which you can using in parameters to `extra()`.  To find out what the alias is you can drop into the shell and `print qset.query`.

See Django documentation on [F objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.F) and [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

**Update:**  It seems you actually don't have to use `extra()`, or figure out what alias django uses, because every time you refer to `response__coding` in your lookups, django will use the alias created initially.  Here's one way to look for differences in either direction:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F
gt = Q(response__coding__value__gt=F('value') + 1)
lt = Q(response__coding__value__lt=F('value') - 1)
match = Q(response__coding__qid='risk', response__coding__coder=4)
qset = Coding.objects.filter(match & (gt | lt), qid='risk', coder=3)
responses = [c.response for c in qset.select_related('response')]
```

See Django documentation on [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

BTW, If you are going to want both Coding instances, you have an N + 1 queries problem here, because django's `select_related()` won't get reverse FK relationships.  But since you have the data in the query already, you could retrieve the required information using the T3 alias as described above and `extra(select={'other_value':'T3.value'})`.  The `value` data from the corresponding Coding record would be accessible as an attribute on the retrieved Coding instance, i.e. as `c.other_value`.

Incidentally, your question is general enough, but it looks like you have an entity-attribute-value schema, which in an RDB scenario is generally considered an anti-pattern.  You might be better off long-term (and this query would be simpler) with a `risk` field:

```
class Coding(models.Model):
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response)
    coder = models.ForeignKey(User)
    risk = models.IntegerField()
    # other fields for other qid 'attribute' names...
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to make it work regardless of whether coder 3 or coder 4 is higher?

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution that works for both cases.